# Algorithm for duplicated but overlapping strings

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to write a method where I'm given a string `s` and I need to return the shortest string which contains `s` as a contiguous substring twice.

However two occurrences of `s` may overlap. For example,

- `aba` returns `ababa`
- `xxxxx` returns `xxxxxx`
- `abracadabra` returns `abracadabracadabra`

My code so far is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwiceString {

    public static String getShortest(String s) {
        int index = -1, i, j = s.length() - 1;
        char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
        String res = s;

        for (i = 0; i < j; i++, j--) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                index = i;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (index != -1) {
            for (i = index + 1; i <= j; i++) {
                String tmp = new String(arr, i, i);
                res = res + tmp;
            }
        } else {
            res = res + res;
        }

        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string: ");
        String word = inp.next();

        System.out.println("The requires shortest string is " + getShortest(word));
    }
}
```

I know I'm probably wrong at the algorithmic level rather than at the coding level. What should be my algorithm?

Comment: +1 because i don't see why somebody down voted, this seems like a pretty valid question to me.

Comment: This looks very much like homework. @CSSS, is this homework?

Comment: @CSSS: This looks a lot like homework.  If it is, you should add the [tag:homework] tag to your question.

Comment: @Esko and Fahim: No, this isn't homework. I was trying out my hands over them (just for the fun of it).

Comment: @CSSS see my code edit, the code i just posted should be what you're looking for

Answer (score 9):

Use a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).  In particular, after you've constructed the tree for `s`, go to the leaf representing the whole string and walk up until you see another end-of-string marker.  This will be the leaf of the longest suffix that is also a prefix of `s`.

Answer (score 3):

As @phs already said, part of the problem can be translated to *"find the longest prefix of s that is also a suffix of s"* and a solution without a tree may be this:

```
public static String getShortest(String s) {
    int i = s.length();
    while(i > 0 && !s.endsWith(s.substring(0, --i))) 
        ;
    return s + s.substring(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you've found your index, and even if it's -1, you just need to append to the original string the substring going from `index + 1` (since index is the last matching character index) to the end of the string. There's a method in String to get this substring.

Answer (score 2):

i think you should have a look at the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm, the partial match table it uses is pretty much what you need (and by the way it's a very nice algorithm ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your input string `s` is, say, `"abcde"` you can easily build a regex like the following (notice that the last character `"e"` is missing!):

```
a(b(c(d)?)?)?$
```

and run it on the string `s`. This will return the starting position of the trailing repeated substring. You would then just append the missing part (i.e. the last N-M characters of `s`, where N is the length of `s` and M is the length of the match), e.g.

```
aba
  ^ match "a"; append the missing "ba"
xxxxxx
 ^ match "xxxxx"; append the missing "x"
abracadabra
       ^ match "abra"; append the missing "cadabra"
nooverlap
--> no match; append "nooverlap"
```

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding you want to do this:

```
input: dog
output: dogdog
--------------
input: racecar
output: racecaracecar
```

So this is how i would do that:

```
 public String change(String input)
{
    StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder(input);

    int patternLocation = input.length();
    for(int x = 1;x < input.length();x++)
    {
        StringBuilder check = new StringBuilder(input);

        for(int y = 0; y < x;y++)
            check.deleteCharAt(check.length() - 1);

        if(input.endsWith(check.toString()))
        {
            patternLocation = x;
            break;
        }
    }

    outputBuilder.delete(0,  input.length() - patternLocation);

    return outputBuilder.toString();
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Doesn't satisfy the requirements, and fails since `string.charAt(string.length())` obviously won't work.

Comment: And should use `StringBuilder` instead of using `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @JBNizet how does it not satisfy the requirements?

Comment: abracadabra should result to abracadabracadabra, not to abracadabrabracadabra. It's well explained in the question. You just care of the first and last chars. It's not what is being asked.

Comment: @Lion hmm i didn't know that StringBuilder was a "replacement" for StringBuffer, i guess ill be using that from now on

Comment: @JBNizet ohh ok i see what you're saying, i didn't see that

Comment: @JBNizet Please see the code i changed it to, i ran it and it worked for me

Comment: If you say it works, I'll believe you. But I can't understand the algorithm. The OP's algorithm is much simpler, and doesn't need two loops. I'll remove my downvite, though.

Comment: `for(int y = 0; y < x;y++) check.deleteCharAt(check.length() - 1);` deletes x characters at the end of `check`. This can be replaced by `check.setLength(check.length() - x)